# Visualizing gradle dependencies in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

Is there a way to visualize project dependencies for a gradle project in Intellij? For a maven project, if you right click in the `pom.xml` you get a `Show dependencies` option but there I don't see such an option for a gradle project.

Does this feature exist for gradle project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small search in IDEA and Google and looks like there is not way to see Gradle dependency but I have found the plugin "Gradle View" which does what you need

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7150

You can open a ticket and maybe they will add a better Gradle support in IDEA 15

Comment: Thanks. I've now opened a ticket for this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141705

Answer (score 0):

In intellij idea you can right click on your project name in "Gradle" window.
If you don't see "Gradle" follow below screen.

[image]

In Gradle window select "Dependency Analyzer"

[image]

Then you can browse for your dependency or analyse it. Like in below example I looked for slf4j dependencies.

[image]